Annotation Processor not getting hit during compilation even though a class with an invalid use of the annotation is present
So, I am working on a data structure for personal use (more like for practice). I have an annotation Implementation which is applied a class that either defines an abstract implementation or a concrete implementation. When it is a concrete implementation, the annotation forces the class to extend a specific top-level class AbstractDataEngine and provide an inner class that implements Iterator.
This is the definition of Implementation

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/**
 * A marker annotation, forces the class which is to be defined as a data engine, to
 * extend {@code AbstractDataEngine} or any of its subclasses and provide an {@code Iterator}
 * implementation.
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Implementation {

    ImplementationType value();

    enum ImplementationType {
        ABSTRACTION, IMPLEMENTATION;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return switch (this){
                case ABSTRACTION -> "abstraction";
                case IMPLEMENTATION -> "implementation";
            };
        }
    }
}

This is the definition of AbstractDataEngine


import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

/**
 * This class defines methods, that will be common to every single data engine, irrespective of type of
 * data structure, or its implementation
 * @param <E> Type of data being stored
 */
@Implementation(Implementation.ImplementationType.ABSTRACTION)
public abstract class AbstractDataEngine<E> implements DataEngine<E>, Iterable<E>{

    //The golden ratio,, generally used as a growth factor for determining new size
    protected final double GOLDEN_RATIO = 1.61803398875;

    //Only for array-based
    protected final double DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 16;
    protected final double GROWTH_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75;
    protected final double SHRINK_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.25;

    protected int activeSize;
    protected int maxCapacity;

    protected AbstractDataEngine(int activeSize, int maxCapacity){
        this.activeSize = activeSize;
        this.maxCapacity = maxCapacity;
    }

    /**
     * When invoked on a data engine that implements an underlying array, will shift all the elements
     * to the beginning, i.e. a sparsely populated array can be so adjusted that all the elements
     * get move to the front
     *
     */
    protected abstract void compress();

    /**
     * When the {@code activeSize} is less than {@code SHRINK_LOAD_FACTOR * maxCapacity}, for an
     * underlying array it will end up shrinking by {@code maxCapacity - Math.floor(GOLDEN_RATIO * maxCapacity)}
     * Cam have an asynchronous implementation in thread-safe data engines.
     *
     */
    protected abstract void shrink();

    /**
     * When the {@code activeSize} is greater than {@code GROWTh_LOAD_FACTOR * maxCapacity}, for an
     * underlying array it will end up growing by {@code maxCapacity - Math.floor(GOLDEN_RATIO * maxCapacity)}
     * Cam have an asynchronous implementation in thread-safe data engines.
     *
     */
    protected abstract void grow();

    /**
     * @return Returns true, if the invoking data engine is empty, false otherwise
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.activeSize == 0;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns max capacity of the data engine, or the max size before growth
     */
    @Override
    public int maxCapacity() {
        return this.maxCapacity;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns current size of data engine
     */
    @Override
    public int getActiveSize() {
        return this.activeSize;
    }

    /**
     * Generates an {@code AtomicReference} of the data engine. Useful when the object has to be
     * used in a thread blocking context without making the data engine asynchronous.
     *
     * @return Returns an {@code AtomicReference} of the invoking data engine
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException Will throw an exception when the invoking data engine is
     *                                       already {@code Thread-Mutable}
     */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends DataEngine<E>> AtomicReference<T> createThreadSafeImage() {
        return new AtomicReference<>((T)this);
    }

    /**
     * The method reverses the invoking data engine when implemented.
     *
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException Thrown when it is unimplemented.
     */
    public abstract void reverse();


}

And finally the processor
package data.core;

import com.google.auto.service.AutoService;

import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind;
import javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier;

@AutoService(javax.annotation.processing.Processor.class)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("de.core.Implementation")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_17)
public class ImplementationAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    private Messager messager;

    // Initialize core components to be used during processing
    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        super.init(processingEnv);
        messager = processingEnv.getMessager();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "Hitting the processor");
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Implementation.class)) {

            //If the element annotated is not a class type
            if(!element.getKind().isClass()) {

                messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,
                        "Implementation must be used on a class", element);
                return true;
            }else if(element.getAnnotation(Implementation.class).value()
                    .equals(Implementation.ImplementationType.ABSTRACTION)
            & !element.getModifiers().contains(Modifier.ABSTRACT)){

                //Invalid abstraction definition
                messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,
                        "An Implementation defined as an ABSTRACTION" +
                        "must be declared abstract", element);
                return true;
            }else if(element.getAnnotation(Implementation.class).value()
                    .equals(Implementation.ImplementationType.IMPLEMENTATION)
            & element.getModifiers().contains(Modifier.ABSTRACT)){

                //Invalid implementation definition
                messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,
                        "An implementation defined as an IMPLEMENTATION" +
                                "cannot be declared abstract", element);
                return true;
            }else if(element.getAnnotation(Implementation.class).value()
                    .equals(Implementation.ImplementationType.IMPLEMENTATION)){

                //All exceptional conditions removed, now checking the specifics
                //If the class does not extend an abstraction
                if(!isSubClassOf((TypeElement) element)){
                    messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,
                            "An implementation must extend "+ AbstractDataEngine.class +
                            " to be considered a valid implementation", element);
                    return true;
                }

                if(!hasEnclosedIterator((TypeElement) element)){
                    messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Implementation does not contain a" +
                            "Iterator implementation", element);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private boolean isSubClassOf(TypeElement element) {
        TypeMirror superClassType = element.getSuperclass();

        while (superClassType.getKind() != TypeKind.NONE){
            if(AbstractDataEngine.class.toString().equals(superClassType.getClass().toString())){
                return true;
            }
            superClassType = ((TypeElement) processingEnv.getTypeUtils().asElement(superClassType))
                    .getSuperclass();
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean hasEnclosedIterator(TypeElement element) {
        for (Element enclosedElement : element.getEnclosedElements()) {
            if (enclosedElement.getKind().isClass()) {
                for (TypeMirror inf : element.getInterfaces()) {
                    if (inf.toString().equals(Iterator.class.getCanonicalName()))
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

I have a class AbstractList that, in theory, should trigger an exceptional condition as per my processor.
package engine.core;

import data.core.Implementation;


/**
 * The top-level abstract class for all List implementations, including thread-safe
 * implementations. It defines methods specific to the behaviour of a list, unique value lists are also considered.
 * @param <E>
 */
@Implementation(Implementation.ImplementationType.ABSTRACTION)
public class AbstractList<E> {

}

I am using AutoService to register my Processor.
I am using Maven as a build system in IntelliJ
Initially I set all the files including any implementations in a single project. I set up Maven to pull my processor during compilation. Yet it compiled without errors. Next I split up the core files without any implementations into a separate module in intelliJ and compiled into a jar with Maven. I used this jar in a separate module which contained implementations, hoping for a hit. Yet it again compiled without triggering the processor.

Which library defines @AutoProcessor? Have you checked that the service definition file in META-INF/services was created correctly? Which Java version do you use? Do you have a module-info.java file?  Does it export the service, too?

I am using AutoService from google. And yes, the META-INF generates correctly. It even shows that it was linked correctly in intellij. And I am not using modules. I am running JDK 17.0.2

Can you clarify how you set up the relationship between the Modules on Maven level? In Maven logic, even if those are Modules of the same Project you still have to declare them as dependencies. Also, what do you mean by "I set up Maven to pull my processor during compilation."?

Thanks but I figured it out, it was basically a bit of an error with the dependencies, I had packaged the processor with the annotation into another jar and let the maven-compiler detect it during compilation, I just added random arguments into the configuration which caused it to ignore the processor, plus I had some error in my logic which caused it to behave abnormally
